# determining if string is null takes 2 arguments for some reason

Tags: java, android

the following code works:

```
String myString = null;
if (myString != null &&  myString.length()> 0     ) {
          System.out.println("this is NOT null");
   }
else{

        System.out.println("yes this is NULL!!");

    }
```

output: yes this is NULL!!

however, the following will give an error:

```
String myString = null;
   if ( myString.length()> 0     ) {

              System.out.println("this is NOT null");
       }
    else{

            System.out.println("yes this is NULL!!");

        }
```

why does the if condition require 2 conditions to check if this string is null ?

Comment: && is short-circuiting.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't. Only this

```
myString != null
```

checks if a `String` value is (not) `null`.

This

```
myString.length()> 0
```

tries to dereference a `String` value in order to invoke the referenced instance's `length()` method. If the value is `null`, a `NullPointerException` will be raised.

> why does the if condition require 2 conditions to check if this string is null ?

Your first condition checks if the value is `null`. If it isn't (`&&` short circuits), your second condition checks that the `String` is not empty.

Comment: so what is the best way to check if a string is null ? is my code ok ?

Comment: @mikemiller There is no best way. There is only one way, as expressed in my answer, using equality operators.

Comment: Most code compilers will look at statements from left to right, if the first part of your statement fails and the operator is an AND (&&) it won't bother to evaluate the second part. It's already failed. In your first example the compiler ignores the second part. In your second example it evaluates .length() on a null, as mentioned a null has no length, so it'll error.

Comment: do i need 2 conditions or can myString != null be enough ?

Comment: @mikemiller That condition is enough to check that `myString` is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use length() method on NULL reference, which is not an object. By checking
 with the `mystring != null && mystring.length() > 0` 
you only check mystring variable, see that it is null and exit the if condition, without invoking the length method.

Fun fact (note the single &):

```
`mystring != null & mystring.length() > 0`
```

Would give you also a NullPointerException, because both conditions would be evaluated.

If you want to do it properly, yaou have to either check  both conditions ( != null && length), or you can use .

Comment: What I wanted to say is that Java uses lazy evaluation for operators - if the condition mystring != null is false ( which means that mystring is null) it DOES NOT try to check its length, but exits. If you omit mystring != null condition, it tries to evalueate null.length(), which alweays returns NullPointerException.

Comment: so is my code ok? and why do i need 2 arguments here?

Comment: Yes, your code which checks `myString != null &&  myString.length()> 0` is OK. It forces the program to ensure that myString is not null and actually HAS length, and then it tries to check if its length is OK. If mystring was null it would not have length and checking it would cause an error.

Comment: is myString != null enough ?

Comment: i mean, do i need 2 conditions or can myString != null be enough ?

Comment: If you only check `myString != null` it will work and accept any string, if you also check `&& myString.length() > 0` it will accept any string besides "" - the empty string with 0 length.

Comment: so which do you recommend? using only one condition or both ?

Comment: It depends what do you really want to check. In basic case, just do `myString != null` and it will be fine.